# correcting kerning for tikz shapes as accents in mid-word

Tags: tikz-pgf, accents

I'm trying to place arrow shapes above certain letters in a text. I tried compensating for the extra space of the `tikzpicture` in mid-word, using `execute at begin picture` and its `end` pair.

The results aren't very good, is there a better way of doing this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\newcommand\toneUp[1]{%
\def\mychar{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    execute at begin picture={
        \pgfmathparse{0.5*(1.6mm-\widthof{\mychar})}
        \hspace*{-\pgfmathresult mm}
    },
    execute at end picture={
        \pgfmathparse{0.5*(1.6mm-\widthof{\mychar})}
        \hspace*{-\pgfmathresult mm}
    }]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (mychar) {\mychar};
    \node[single arrow, minimum height=5mm, minimum width=7mm, single arrow head extend=3mm, single arrow head indent=1mm, scale=0.3, red, fill=red, rotate=90, above=0.3mm of mychar.north, anchor=west] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

ārop\toneUp{i}tehi\\
paṇṇ\toneUp{ā}kār\toneUp{a}\\
bh\toneUp{ū}te

\end{document}
```

Comment: some of your white space comes from the word space after the picture you are missing a `%`, you need `\end{tikzpicture}%`. I can't help with the tikz, but probably I would set the character normally, ie just start (or end) your macro with `#1` and then use a zero-sized tikzpicture to overlay the arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** better arrows but the kerning is not completely perfect because `\mychar` is draw alone in this node.

You can use `overlay` option to remove your arrow from automatic bounding box calculation of tikzpicture.

You cans use `em` or `ex` dimension to adapt automatically the dimension of your arrow to the current font dimension.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\newcommand\toneUp[1]{%
\def\mychar{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
  \node (mychar) {\mychar};
  \node[
  overlay,
  single arrow,
  inner sep=.05em,
  minimum height=.25em,
  minimum width=.35em,
  single arrow head extend=.15em, 
  single arrow head indent=.05em,
  red,
  fill=red, 
  rotate=90,
  above=0.3mm of mychar.north,
  anchor=west] {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

ārop\toneUp{i}tehi

paṇṇ\toneUp{ā}kār\toneUp{a}

bh\toneUp{ū}te

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the `overlay` example!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the fonts installed properly but you need to cancel the bounding box update due to the arrow. So you can use `pgfinterruptpicture` environment that allows you to avoid the bounding box updates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\newcommand\toneUp[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (mychar) {#1};
\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}
    \node[single arrow, minimum height=5mm, 
          minimum width=7mm, single arrow head extend=3mm, 
        single arrow head indent=1mm, scale=0.3, red, fill=red, 
        rotate=90, above=0.3mm of mychar.north, anchor=west] {};
\end{pgfinterruptpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

ārop\toneUp{i}tehi\\
paṇṇ\toneUp{ā}kār\toneUp{a}\\
bh\toneUp{ū}te

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that the `overlay` option is easier.

Comment: @PaulGaborit You are right, I keep forgetting that. It maps to `pgfinterruptpicture` anyway (if you do a lot of things adding overlay to each might become laborious though).

Comment: I believe that you can apply `overlay` to a `scope`.